# Adding UserControls Dynamically and Finding

Tags: user-controls

I am adding user controls dynamically to a page which all adhere to an interface.  I want to be able to find these controls again upon Postback.  I tried looking through the control collection but to no avail?  Please help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The controls need to be added again on PostBack. They should be added early in the page lifecycle, e.g. PageInit.

Remember that when a PostBack occurs, the control collection has to be built from scratch. Where the controls are added to the page declaratively - as markup in the .aspx - the ASP.NET framework automatically instantiates and adds the controls, but you still need to manually add any dynamically created controls. Adding the controls early in the page life-cycle ensures that viewstate and postback data are handled correctly, and any events are raised.